# Can I define a custom getter for a C# auto-implemented property (a.k.a. auto backing field)?

Tags: c#, getter-setter, syntactic-sugar, automatic-properties, backing-field

Note: I know how to accomplish this *without* using auto-implemented properties, but I'm wondering if C# has a built-in way to do this.

Let's say I have this simple example of an auto-implemented property (a.k.a. auto backing field):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(){}
    public string MyString { get; private set; }
}
```

Now, I would like to return a custom exception in the getter if the auto backing field is null:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(){}
    public string MyString
    {
        get
        {
            return [backing field] ?? throw new Exception("MyString is null");
        }
        private set;
    } = null;
}
```

Do newer C# versions support something like this? Perhaps there is some syntactic sugar that I can use in place of `[backing field]` to access the backing field that is automatically created by the compiler?

Note on putting an exception in the getter: I know it shouldn't be a habit. But Microsoft does it occasionally; for example, the property `HttpContext.Request.Form` will throw an exception if the request is not of the proper content-type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# 3.0 Auto-Properties - Is it possible to add custom behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116142/c-sharp-3-0-auto-properties-is-it-possible-to-add-custom-behaviour)

Comment: "Do newer C# versions support something like this?" no they don't

Comment: a: no; b: it is *incredibly* hostile to put exceptions in property getters, and it breaks a lot of expected rules re data binding, serialization, etc; much better to put the validation in the setter!

Comment: @MarcGravell Microsoft does it occasionally--the property `HttpContext.Request.Form` will throw an exception if the request is not of the proper content-type

Comment: @user3163495 that doesn't make it a good API decision that should be replicated without thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised noone mentioned the `field` keyword, it is exactly what you are asking for (what you would use instead of `[backing field]` in your example). It was supposed to be shipped with C# 10. It seems it is going to be shipped with C# 11 instead (?)

Search for **Field Keyword** [here](https://dev.to/dotnetsafer/leaked-c-11-features-the-best-christmas-gift-from-microsoft-pn1).

Comment: someone mentioned this in the comments in my question above and I asked them to make it an answer but they instead deleted their comment and never made it an answer

Comment: It isn't released as GA yet so I didn't mention it. IMO the OP was asking about a specific implementation of the getter that is not best practice even with a field keyword so I answered from that perspective.

Comment: @user3163495: I made it an answer, as you requested, but it got downvoted as I feared it would, and since it wasn't the accepted answer yet, I deleted it. The reason I was hesitant to post it as an answer is for the reason Fred mentioned, that it's not GA yet, and I'm sure it was downvoted for that reason, too.

Comment: Blogs that talk about features under consideration are nice but don't pay attention to the version number until it actually ships.  Follow the [proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/140) and read the linked LDM notes.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not access to backing field in this way.

You must define backing field and validate it.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(){}
    private string? _myString
    public string MyString
    {
        get
        {
            return _myString ?? throw new Exception("MyString is null");
        }
        private set => _myString  = value;
    } = null;
}
```

As Fred said, its better to validate it outside of property.

Answer (score 1):

Put validation in the setter and/or ensure that the constructor sets a valid/non-null default value.

Or make the property nullable to hint to the customer that they have to account for a null value possibility.

Alternatively (but less optimally for multiple reasons), make the property private and add a method for accessing it.

Strongly advise against a property get directly throwing an exception. You or the consumer will dislike the results at some point.